# What would happen to a Menos or an Arrancar killed with a Zanpakuto?

Tags: bleach

It was said that a Hollow killed with a Zanpakuto is cleansed of all of his post-mortem sins, and is sent to soul society (unless he had committed sins in his lifetime, then he goes to Hell).

What would then when a Menos, which easily contains hundreds if not thousands of souls, is killed with a Zanpakuto?

Would all of the souls be released? Or perhaps the souls fused into one? If so, does that mean that Ulqiorra is somewhere in Soul Society right now?

Is such a thing explained anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is mentioned anywhere, but what I think would be logical (but does not happen in the anime/manga) is that the myriad of hollows suppressed within a Menos are released (since the dominant personality has been destroyed) while those that were damaged in the process of the attack (e.g. those that constitute the wounded flesh) would be purified. So a large-scale attack that can obliterate a Menos might purify all of the souls.

Comment: But in reality, when Ulqiorra died, he desintigrated, he didn't go **super soul nuclear explosion**, even though he was most likely a vasto lorde, with possibly *millions* of souls sealed inside of him.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't happen, so some logical consistency was lost... but I don't think there will be any answer better than speculation anyway.